# Best way to resolve react-hooks/exhaustive-deps warning

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

Consider this contrived code snippet.

```
const foo = () => {return 1;} 
const bar = useMemo(() => {return foo();}, [foo])
```

When I trigger a react-hooks/exhaustive-deps warning, I'll get a message like this.

`The 'foo' function makes the dependencies of useMemo Hook (at line 2) change on every render. Move it inside the useMemo callback. Alternatively, wrap the definition of 'foo' in its own useCallback() Hook.`

The warning gives me 2 recommendations: 1) bring `foo` inside of  `bar`'s useMemo callback, or 2) wrap the function inside a useCallback.

I could certainly do either. I'm just wondering: **Is either of those options preferable over the other, and if so then why?** And if your answer is "it depends", what exactly does it depend on?

Comment: Is this maybe with **useEffect** for example?

Comment: @NtshemboHlongwane You *could* get the same sort of warning with useEffect, so I think this question applies to useEffect as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both ways work just fine. The preference is based on the code and what you are doing with them.

For instance, if you use `foo` in more than that one location, then moving it inside the `useMemo` callback wouldn't work.

If you are only using `foo` in the useMemo callback, then it makes sense to define it in there.

In that case, it would look something like:

```
const bar = useMemo(() => {
  const foo = () => 1;
  return foo();
  // include foo's dependencies in the deps array
}, []);
```

or you could define it inline:

```
const bar = useMemo(() => {
  return 1;
  // include foo's dependencies in the deps array
}, []);
```

Comment: @ZacheryHaber Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With useEffect how I like to resolve this is having a cleanup function

```
const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(true);


useEffect(()=>{

    if (mounted){
        buzz();

    }

    //Cleanup function
    return ()=>{
        setMounted(false);
    }
}, [mounted]) //hook dependency
```

Comment: Trying to use `useEffect` as componentDidMount is an [antipattern](https://reacttraining.com/blog/useEffect-is-not-the-new-componentDidMount/). It's all about making sure things stay in sync rather than follow a lifecycle.

Comment: Okay I understand what you and blog actually makes sense, so I have been facing this problem without using clean up function see when you use something like ```pusher``` without cleanup function the content occurs more than once even with the bracket given there, so can you please explain how to solve such?

Comment: You definitely want to use cleanup functions. I know I've used effects to subscribe/unsubscribe from socket-io events. I've never used pusher, so I don't know the intricacies there. From a brief look, I found this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@harelpls/use-pusher module that you could potentially look through or use